# Perl string manipulation and find

Tags: regex, string, perl, search, substitution

I am currently working on a phonebook program for a class and I am having a little bit of trouble with the regex part in order to format my text and find what im looking for. Firstly, I am having trouble editing my phone number text to what I want. I am able to find the text that have 7 numbers in a row (777777) but I am unable to substitute it to (1-701-777-777).

```
if($splitIndex[1] =~ m/^(\d{3}\d{4})/) {
      $splitIndex[1] =~ s/([\d{3}][\d{4}])/1-701-[$1]-[$2]/;
      print "Updated: $splitIndex[1]";
    }
```

When I run this code the output ends up being (wont let me imbed image here is output https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd0oG.jpg).

Secondly, I am having trouble doing the actual regex part for the searching. I save all the possible letter combinations in $letofSearch and the number order combination in $numOfSearch. Through playing around in regex I have figured out if I do [$numOfSearch]+[$numOfSearch[-1]...[$numOfSearch[1] it gives me the correct find for the numbers but I am unable to write it properly in my code.

```
    #If user input is only numbers
    if($searchValue =~ m/(\D)/) {
      #print "Not a number\n";
      if($splitIndex[1] =~ m/([$numOfSearch]+)/) {
        if($found == 0) {
            print "$splitIndex[0]:$splitIndex[1]\n";
            $found = 1;
        }
      }
      if($splitIndex[0] =~ m/([$letOfSearch])/i) {
        if($found == 0) {
            print "$splitIndex[0]:$splitIndex[1]\n";
            $found = 1;
        }
      }
      $found = 0;
    } else {
      #If it is a number search for that number combo immedietly
      if($splitIndex[1] =~ m/([$numOfSearch]+)/) {
        if($found == 0) {
            print "$splitIndex[0]:$splitIndex[1]\n";
            $found = 1;
        }
      }
      if($splitIndex[0] =~ m/([$letOfSearch])/i) {
        if($found == 0) {
            print "$splitIndex[0]:$splitIndex[1]\n";
            $found = 1;
        }
      }
      $found = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. What do you think `()` and `[]` do in a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if($splitIndex[1] =~ m/^(\d{3}\d{4})/) {
      $splitIndex[1] =~ s/([\d{3}][\d{4}])/1-701-[$1]-[$2]/;
      print "Updated: $splitIndex[1]";
    }
```

try this:

```
if ($splitIndex[1] =~ s/(\d{3})(\d{4})/1-701-$1-$2/)
{
    print "Updated: $splitIndex[1]";
}
```

In regular expressions, a set of square brackets (`[` and `]`) will match *one and only one* character, regardless of what's between the brackets.  So when you write `[\d{3}][\d{4}]`, that will match *exactly two characters*, because you are using *two* sets of `[]`.  And those two characters will be one of `\d` (any digit), `{`, `3`, `4`, or `}`, because that's what you wrote inside the brackets.

The order doesn't matter inside of the square brackets of a regular expression, so `[\d{3}]` is the same as `[}1527349806{3]`.  As you can see, that's probably not what you wanted.

What you meant to do was *capture* the `\d{3}` and `\d{4}` strings, and you do that with a regular set of *capturing* parentheses, like this:  `(\d{3})(\d{4})`

Since you had only one set of parentheses (that is, you had `([\d{3}][\d{4}])`) and it contained exactly two `[]`s, it was putting exactly two characters into $1, and nothing at all into $2.  That's why, when you attempted to use $2 in the second half of your `s///`, it was complaining about an uninitialized value in $2.  You were attempting to use a value ($2) that simply wasn't set.

(Also, you were doing two sets of matches:  One for the `m//`, and one for the `s///`.  I simply removed the `m//` match and kept the `s///` match, using its return value to determine if we need to print() anything.)

The second part of the `s///` does not use regular expressions, so any `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `(`, or `)` will show up literally as that character.  So if you don't want square brackets in the final phone number, don't use them.  That's why I used `s/.../1-701-$1-$2/;` instead of `s/.../1-701-[$1]-[$2]/;`.

So when you wrote `s/([\d{3}][\d{4}])/1-701-[$1]-[$2]/`, the `([\d{3}][\d{4}])` part was putting two characters into $1, and nothing into $2.  That's why you got a result that contained `[77]` (which was $1 surrounded by brackets) and `[]` (which was $2 (an uninitialized value) surrounded by brackets).

As for the second part of your post, I notice that you use a lot of capturing parentheses in your regular expressions, but you never actually use what you capture.  That is, you never use $1 (or $2).  For example, you write:

```
if($searchValue =~ m/(\D)/) {
```

which has `m/(\D)/`, yet you never use $1 anywhere in that code.  I wonder:  What's the point of capturing that non-digit character if you don't use it anywhere in your code?

I've seen programmers get confused and mix up the purpose of parentheses and square brackets.  When using regular expressions, square brackets (`[` and `]`) **match** (not capture) *exactly one* character.  What they match is *not* put in $1, $2, or any other $n.

Parentheses, on the other hand, *capture* whatever they match, by setting $1 (or $2, $3, etc.) to what was matched.  In general, you shouldn't use parentheses unless you plan on capturing and using that match later.  (The main exception to this rule is if you need to group a set of matches, like this:  `m/I have a (cat|dog|bird)/`.)

Many programmers confuse square brackets and parentheses in regular expressions, and try to use them interchangeably.  They'll write something like `m/I have a [cat|dog|bird]/` and not realize that it's the same as `m/I have a [abcdgiort|]/` (which doesn't capture anything, since there are no parentheses), and wonder why their program complains that $1 is an uninitialized value.

This is a common mistake, so don't feel bad if you didn't know the difference.  Now you know, and hopefully you can figure out what needs to be corrected in the second part of your code.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes thank you for taking the time for a great explanation. The first part worked.

Comment: @J-L As the old saying goes:

You have a problem.
You decide to solve it with Regular Expressions.
Great! Now you have *two* problems.

Excellent answer.